# jsf and javascript confirmation dialog box

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a Java Server Face form with a few input rates, after user puts in the values and click on Save on the JSF page. The validation will happen. I want display warning messages if validation failed in a JavaScript confirmation box.

1. If the user insists that the updated inputs are correct then they can click on "Ok" button to save the data in the JSF page.

or

2. They can click on "Cancel" button to change the data in the form.

I am not sure how to have JavaScript confirmation box OK button to trigger saving operation in JSF.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did try to use document.write() but there is no way to all back to the jsf.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since we are not using PrimeFace package at this point, we decided to add a button on the same page based on a specific condition. The Javascript popup does not appear to have a way to call back to the jsf with the current state.